# Typescript: Define aparameter of a function to have one of two Interfaces

Tags: typescript

I have a function that could have 2 different payloads of the 1st parameter:

```
interface payload1 {
    userId: string;
    partnerId: string;
} 

interface payload2 {
    userToken: string;
    partnerKey: string;
}

function loadData(input: payload1 | payload2){
    if(input.userId){
        // Load Data by userID
    }
}
```

But typescript says:

[image]

Demo on ts playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgA5wJ4BsD2cAmAjMgN4BQylyArgM7QCS+AXMrWFKAOYDcFV6KGBCMWbDtz4BfZGTKhIsRCnTY8+AEyl+lOtAAqOANYQQrdpxC8daOEJFQA0hAzmJV6XJjUQCMMBwQZFwCABE4MDgAClBUajBWVRCiZAAfWzUCDQBKcipkYBgYkDiwADo9KCZcm3yAejrkABl1ZHDI5AAjDBp6KtCbKTIpIA

**Question**

How i can help typescript to understand input cloud be payload1 OR payload2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use predicates:

```
interface payload1 {
  userId: string;
  partnerId: string;
}

interface payload2 {
  userToken: string;
  partnerKey: string;
}

function isPayload1(input: payload1 | payload2): input is payload1 {
  return (input as payload1) !== undefined;
}

function loadData(input: payload1 | payload2) {
  if (isPayload1(input) && input.userId) {
  }
}
```

check out the docs for more info
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Comment: You should probably check if `userId` is present *inside* of the typeguard, not afterwards.